# When weakly convergence implies the norm convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Suppose I have a finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$. I have doubts about the following statement:
In a reflexive Banach space weakly compact set implies the norm compact. Is the following statement true?

I have read that the above is true now my doubt is if $X$ is finite-dimensional and if will the above result holds for the $L^p(X)$ case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the statement is true.

Take a infinite dimensional reflexive Banach-Space $X$ (for example $L^p(X),  1 < p < \infty$). Now look at the closed unit ball $\overline{B_1(0)} \subset X$.

1.) $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is not norm compact.

*Proof:* 
This is characteristic for an infinte dimensional Banach-space, indeed the following statement is true (Riesz Lemma):

$$\text{dim} \ X = \infty \iff \overline{B_1(0)} \text{ is not norm compact.}$$

2.) $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is weakly compact.

*Proof:* 
Take a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \subset \overline{B_1(0)}$. Clearly $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} $ is bounded, and thus, because $X$ is reflexive, has a weakly converging subsequence $\{x_{n'}\}_{n'=0}^{\infty} \rightharpoonup x \in X$. Because any convex and closed set in $X$ is also weakly sequential closed it follows that $x \in \overline{B_1(0)}$. So $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is **weakly sequential compact**.

(Eberlein-Šmulian theorem tells you that **weakly sequential compact** and **weakly compact** are equivalent in reflexive Banach-spaces).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem